# css-transform animation causing to flickering

Tags: css

My code is in here http://jsfiddle.net/JaB5S/

You can click the blue page to run the animation.

But whenever you do though, you can see the texts flickering until the animation is done. The text on the right side even disappears.

I've read somewhere that `backface-visibility: hidden;` should solve the problem, but I already have it but still cant fix it.

This is my first time working with css animations so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `.toggleClass` in your jQuery instead of the if statement. [Like in this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/JaB5S/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is adding

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

to `#main-container`, I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JaB5S/2/

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Could you explain what was happening and why this would fix it? Thanks!

Comment: The transform-style property specifies how nested elements are rendered in 3D space. This property must be used together with the transform property.

Comment: You could also use `.toggleClass` in your jQuery instead of the if statement. [Like in this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/JaB5S/3/)

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks man! I didnt know about that. I just hit 2 birds with 1 stone.