# CSS transition flicker in Internet Exproler

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

I have problem with this code in internet explorer:

CSS:

```
.nav-fillpath a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.4;
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
.nav-fillpath a strong {
    color: #cd575b;
}

.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-fillpath a::before,
.nav-fillpath a::after,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::before,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    max-width: 2px;
    height: 50%;
    background: #3e3e3e;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::before,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::after {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #cd575b;
}

.nav-fillpath a::before,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::before {
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(125deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(125deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.nav-fillpath a::after,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::after {
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-125deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-125deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;

}

.nav-fillpath h3 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}

.nav-fillpath a.next h3 {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::before,
.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::after {
    height: 50%;
}

.nav-fillpath a:hover::before,
.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(135deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(135deg);
}


.nav-fillpath a:hover::after,
.nav-fillpath a:hover .icon-wrap::after {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}


.nav-fillpath a:hover h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) translateX(0%);
    transform: translateY(-100%) translateX(0%);
}
```

Here is JSFiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/74Hzu/
```

OK solution is delete display: block; from here

```
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and here is FIXED JSFiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/74Hzu/4/
```

When I am hovering nav-fillpath the after part starts flicker, but only in internet explorer, chrome works fine. Any idea where could be problem? I set -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden; on both (before and after), but it also  doesnt work

Comment: webkit is for `safari` and `chrome`, so I am not sure what that would do to fix your issue

Comment: yeah true :D damn overwork :D any idea how to fix IE ?

Comment: tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551744/css-transform-animation-causing-to-flickering/24552135#24552135

Comment: no it is fix just for webkit as @imbondbaby wrote I need something for IE, chrome works fine, but thnak you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-ms` for every `-webkit` in your code.

- -webkit (for Webkit browsers, Chrome and Safari)
- -o (for Opera)
- -moz (for Firefox)
- -ms (for IE)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/74Hzu/3/)

**Upate:**

Issue was resolved after removing `display:block;`

Comment: thank you, but I doesnt for, even in your demo it still flickers - I am using IE11

Comment: Try the new demo now, fixed some stuff in the code.. Works fine in IE9

Comment: is this the new demo? http://jsfiddle.net/74Hzu/3/ - still doesnt work :D damn you microsoft :D :D

Comment: Try this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />` in the `head` part of your code

Comment: meta tag just disable animation - it jumps from one position to another, but nothing is flickering :D

Comment: I didnt really see any animation here in IE9, I just saw the text appear... what is it supposed to do?

Comment: :D oh it should animate on hover and parts after and before should have a lesser angle (sorry for my english, I don't know how to exactly describe it) and text should slide up

Comment: oh finaly, thank you for your help, but it was display: block; which cause this flickering :D

Answer (score 1):

For me setting the `backface-visibility` (css attribute) to `visible` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks! that helped me a lot!